# Superagent Response Scope Issue with React.JS

Tags: javascript, scope, superagent

I'm using react.JS and have an ajax request in the view en lieu of flux.

The response works perfectly, the problem is I can't access the resp body outside of the end function.

here is my code-

```
    var student= null;
    request
                .get(APIConfig.PATH.TEACHER+"class/"+classid+"/student/"+thing.id)
                .end(function(err,resp){
                    student= resp.body;
                    console.log(student);
                });
    console.log(thing);
    console.log(student);
```

the first console log for student shows me the data i need for my view.
the second console log for student shows null (from the first variable). this is definitely a scope issue, i was wondering how to get around this to access resp.body outside the function?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a scope issue, it is an async (timing) issue.

The `console.log` will be executed before the callback of the request, the two main ways to do this will be with either callbacks or [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Callback:

```
var getStudent = function(callback){
    request
        .get(APIConfig.PATH.TEACHER+"class/"+classid+"/student/"+thing.id)
        .end(function(err,resp){
            callback(resp.body);
        });
});

getStudent(function(student){
    console.log(student);
});
```

Promise:

```
var getStudent = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        request
            .get(APIConfig.PATH.TEACHER+"class/"+classid+"/student/"+thing.id)
            .end(function(err,resp){
                resolve(resp.body);
            });
    });
});

getStudent()
    .then(function(student){
        console.log(student);
    });
```